# VBA Loop through rows with multiple ranges and conditions

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range, conditional-statements

Disclaimer: New to VBA

I have an Excel sheet where I would like to build a VBA that does the following things.

1. My requirement is to fill a value in row `Z` based on a formula determined by the text in row `M`.
2. The formula deals with summing values from row `A`, `B`, `C` in different combinations (determined by text in row `M`).
3. Loop this for each row starting from row `5` to row `10000`.

Eg:
If cell `M5 = Apple`, then `Z5 = A5+B5`;
If cell `M9 = Samsung`, then `Z9 = C9+A9`

I know a nested `IF` formula does it easily but there are just too many conditions and I'm looking for an automatic and cleaner route.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked on here for any vba examples that may start to show you what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not a VBA, but I think this will solve the issue:

The solution requires two parts:
a) A table (or named range) to hold the string value to match, and two columns to be added.  This table (BrandEq - my example) is essentially a map to indicate which cells are to be summed.  Where the column (A,B,C,...) is followed by a '#" for the row to be added in later.

b) A custom formula (detailed below) in each cell (z, in your case) to return the sum of the appropriate columns.

[[Please see the attached image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgPhH.png)

Personally, I prefer tables, but either that or a named range is recommend because additional "brands" and combinations (Cell1,Cell2) (my example) can be added easily and the formula automatically updates, so no going back to the base formula.

The the "z cell" formula is: 
    `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$D15,BrandEq,2,FALSE),"#",TEXT(ROW(),"#####"))) +INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$D15,BrandEq,3,FALSE),"#",TEXT(ROW(),"#####")))`

This may be easier to understand working from the 'inside-out':
    VLOOKUP (from the 'DATA' table/range- current row brand column,into the 'BRANDEQ' table/range, return the contents of the corresponding column - note 2 on the first line and 3 on the second line, FALSE=exact matches on the lookup value)
with this value (eg. a#) ->
    SUBSTITUTE( the hashtag '#' place holder, with the current row() as a text() value)
    Indirect( return the corresponding value of that cell -- from the data table, the formula is entered in 'zval' row 14 (my example) (eg. 'a#' -> a11 = 100)

This formula is called a second time, but this time returning the 'Cell2 value, all else is the same function. (eg. 'b#' ->b11 = 15)

The results are added together.

Row 11, for example, parses as follows:
    INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$D11,BrandEq,2,FALSE),"#",TEXT(ROW(),"#####")))
    +
    INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$D11,BrandEq,3,FALSE),"#",TEXT(ROW(),"#####")))

```
INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP('Apple',BrandEq,2,FALSE),"#",TEXT(14,"#####")))  
+      
INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP('Apple',BrandEq,3,FALSE),"#",TEXT(14,"#####")))

INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE("a#","#","11")) + INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE("b#","#","11"))

INDIRECT("a11") + INDIRECT("b11")

 100 + 15

 115
```

If additional/different cells need to be reference they only need be included in the 'BrandEQ' Table.  Note: the cells be referenced do not need to be contiguous - they can be spread throughout the row.